# Suppress messages in markdown, but not in R console

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I currently use the following header:

````
```{r, message=FALSE} 
foo <- function(x) message(x)
for(i in 1:10) foo(i)
```
````

Inside this code chunk, there is a loop over simulated scenarios, with `message()` function that prints status of currently executed scenario.

I would like to suppress those messages from display in RStudio and final HTML output, but I still want to control the simulation progress and see the `message()` output in console. Is this achievable? Maybe with other arguments/functions?

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal reproducible example first](https://yihui.name/en/2017/09/the-minimal-reprex-paradox/)? I'm asking because `message=FALSE` means exactly what you wanted: write the message in the console. If it doesn't work, there must be something else wrong.

Comment: no it apparently does not work this way, but since you ask, I have added a simple example

Comment: I think you refer to the fact that messages might be printed out during actual compilation of HTML file. It does not cover situation when I am running code within RStudio without knitting to evaluate code correctness, yet still the code is within markdown's code chunk.

Comment: You didn't mention RStudio in your question, and I just added the `rstudio` tag to your question. This is a very important piece of information that you omitted, and also what confused me. Anyway, this is an issue specific to the RStudio IDE. If you click the Knit button, you can certainly see the messages. I don't know why the messages are not printed when you click the `Run Current Chunk` button.

Comment: I wasn’t aware it is a significant difference, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write/append status to a file (this is a workaround solution, there should be a more direct answer).

For example:

```
file <- file("status.txt", open = "wt")
sink(file, type = "message")
message("all good")
```

In this example message won't be displayed - it'll be written to a `status.txt` file.

In you're using specific function and iterating over a set you can try this example:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    message(x)
}

file <- file("status.txt", open = "wt")
sink(file, type = "message")
for(i in 1:3) {
    foo(i)
}
```

Function `foo` should return (message) value, however it appends it to a `status.txt` file.

You can track changes in `status.txt` file using bash `tail` command with `-f` argument. First send R to background and then use `tail -f status.txt` in your console.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to put this in the start of your file.

```
mymessage <- function (text) {   
  if(knitr::opts_knit$get('out.format') != NULL) message(text) 
}
```

There are various ways to know if you are within knitr, recent versions have `knitr::is_latex_output` and similar.

Comment: I think I know where this is going, but it does not work (`argument is of length zero`) and I think there should there be `==` ?

Comment: I replaced comparison with `!is.null()` (obviously), so I don't have an error now. But it does not work anyway.